# split text to create table with answers from a suvery?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with answers from a survey that looks like this:

```
df = structure(list(Part.2..Question.1..Response = c("You did not know about the existence of the course", 
"The email you received was confusing and you did not know what to do", 
"Other:", "You did not know about the existence of the course", 
"The email you received was confusing and you did not know what to do", 
"The email you received was confusing and you did not know what to do|Other:", 
"You think is not worth your time", "No Answer", "You think is not worth your time", 
"You think is not worth your time", "You did not know about the existence of the course", 
"You did not know about the existence of the course", "You think is not worth your time|The email you received was confusing and you did not know what to do|You did not know about the existence of the course", 
"You think is not worth your time", "You did not know about the existence of the course", 
"You did not know about the existence of the course", "You think is not worth your time|Other:", 
"You think is not worth your time", "No Answer", "You did not know about the existence of the course", 
"You think is not worth your time", "You think is not worth your time", 
"You did not know about the existence of the course", "You did not know about the existence of the course", 
"You think is not worth your time"), group = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("control", "treatment1", 
"treatment2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Part.2..Question.1..Response", 
"group"), row.names = c(151L, 163L, 109L, 188L, 141L, 158L, 131L, 
32L, 86L, 53L, 148L, 64L, 89L, 30L, 159L, 23L, 40L, 101L, 173L, 
165L, 15L, 156L, 2L, 174L, 41L), class = "data.frame")
```

Some people select multiple answers, for example:

```
df$Part.2..Question.1..Response[13]
```

I want to create a table that has the number of people that selected a given answers for each "group":

```
                                                                                        control treatment1 treatment2
  You think is not worth your time                                                      0          0          0
  The email you received was confusing and you did not know what to do                  10          1          4
  You did not know about the existence of the course                                    4          4          1
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Did you try `table(df)`? Is that what you are after?

Comment: yep, that does not work because of the people selecting more than one option. For example, df$Part.2..Question.1..Response[13]

Comment: My `cSplit` function would be handy here. [Get it from Git Hub](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733), and then just try: `table(cSplit(df, 1, "|", "long"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first split the responses on the "|" and turn multiple responses into multiple rows. Then, after doing that, I can do a simple `table()`

```
dd<-do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, 
    group=df$group, 
    resp=strsplit(df$Part.2..Question.1..Response,"|", fixed=T)
))
with(dd, table(resp, group))
```

You will get results like

```
                                                        group
resp                                         control treatment1 treatment2
  You did not know about the existence ...     6          1          3
  The email you received was confusing ...     1          2          1
  Other:                                       1          0          2
  You think is not worth your time             1          5          4
  No Answer                                    0          1          1
```

Comment: I was working on a very similar solution without do.call. My code was 3 times more complicated. Thanks!